What is the first mention of the classical modular polynomial?
The classical modular polynomial gives a (singular) plane model for the modular curve $X_0(N)$.
I'm curious about the history of these polynomials, in particular, where and when were they first considered?
I know that Kronecker considered them in some form (likely in terms of elliptic functions during his work on the early theory of complex multiplication), but was this the first time they were studied? Or do they appear earlier?

Milne writes in his notes on pp.. 84 and 85 of his notes on modular forms
https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/MF110.pdf
that they were introduced by Kronecker.  Perhaps in Serge Vladut's book  Kronecker's Jugendtraum and modular functions you can find something helpful.
